# Implementing an interface in Javascript using flow-runtime

Tags: javascript, inheritance, interface, babeljs

I am using `flow-runtime` plugin for `babel` to generate dynamically typechecked javascript code. The following is the workflow I am using

- write static javascript code (with flow annotations)
- compile this code using babel to convert flow annotations to typechecked code
- run this compiled code in node.js

The following workflow gives me an ability to write typescript type code, but with type checking only where I want.

So, now that we understand what I am doing, let me explain what I am trying to achieve

I basically need to build a class called `Interface`, which will do exactly what it sounds like. This class will be extended by classes that are supposed to be interfaces, and then extended by other classes. Something like this :

```
class Interface() {
    constructor() {
        ...
    }

    // interface superclass, supposed to be extended by all interfaces
    // this class will provide all the utility methods required 
    // by an interface, such as validating the implementation of the 
    // interface, ...

    validateInterfaceImplementation() {
        ...
    }
}

// interface definition
class FooInterface extends Interface {
    constructor() {
        super();
        ...
    }
}

// actual class, that will implement the "FooInterface" interface
class Foo extends FooInterface {
    constructor() {
        super();
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I want to enforce strict implementation of the `FooInterface`. That means that I want a way to define all the methods that the `FooInterface interface` expects to be implemented, and validation that all these methods have been implemented by the `Foo` class.

What I have tried looks something like this

```
// interface.js
// @flow-runtime
class Interface<T> {
    constructor(t: T) {
        (this: T); // let flow validate that the interface is implemented
    }
}

// FooInterface.js
// @flow-runtime
type foInterface = {
    bar(param: string): number;
}

class FooInterface extends Interface<fooInterface> {
    constructor() {
        super(fooInterface);
    }
}

// Foo.js
// @flow-runtime
class Foo extends FooInterface {

}

new Foo(); // should throw an error, because the interface is not implemented
           // (the function bar is not defined)
```

I am facing multiple problems with this approach

- I am not sure how to implement the generic class `Interface<T>`. In think my implementation is incorrect, and the compiled babel code also throws an error, but I can't figure out how to do this.
- I am not even sure whether this method will work or not, or whether this is the best way to approach this problem.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

As of flow-runtime 0.5.0 you can use Flow's `implements` keyword combined with Flow interfaces. I think this will give you what you want without having to create the concrete classes at all:

```
// @flow
// @flow-runtime
interface IPoint<T> {
  x: T;
  y: T;
}

interface IJSON {
  toJSON (): any;
}

class Point implements IPoint<number>, IJSON {
  x: number = 123;
  y: number = 456;
  toJSON () {
     return {x: this.x, y: this.y};
  }
}
```